# Bower not finding a package in Angular on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, bower

I'm following Thinkster's tutorial about Angular on Rails(https://thinkster.io/angular-rails#jumping-in-with-angular).
In this tutorial, I install front-end dependencies following way:

```
bower install angular angular-ui-router bootstrap --save
```

Then I require bootstrap in `application.css` in following way:

```
 *= require bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

And here is `application.js` file:

```
//= require angular
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require angular-ui-router
//= require_tree .
```

When I run the rails server I get following errors,

```
1. couldn't find file 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap' with type 'text/css'
2. couldn't find file 'angular' with type 'application/javascript'
```

Here is `.bowerrc` file:

```
{
  "directory":"vendor/assets/bower_components"
}
```

Here is an error I'm getting from rails server console:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap' with type 'text/css'):
    2: <html>
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>FlapperNews</title>
    5:  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:14
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1398966333390810206_70171728569860'
```

I confirm that bootstrap and angular are correctly installed in Rails app. 
[image]

But it seems like it is not finding it in the app. What could be the problem?

Comment: I too am stuck at this point. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: I just figured this out. I actually had a typo. I can commit my code to a repo if you would like to look at it and see if there is anything different.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use bower-rails (https://github.com/rharriso/bower-rails) which can help you to manage your front-end dependencies in a Rails app. You can then add your dependencies to your Bowerfile and `rake bower:install` which will install your dependencies to /vendor/assets/bower_components, so now you can require them on your application.css or application.js files.

I think that having a bower_components folder in the root path of your Rails app is not the way to go, since its contents won't be visible to the Asset Pipeline (more info. here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Comment: The tutorial I'm following was saying to use that way instead of installing bower-rails because of following reason: There's also a bower-rails gem if you prefer a more Gemfile-like syntax to your bower.json and rake tasks that wrap the bower commands, however, this will be another dependency in your Gemfile, and also requires Bower to be installed via npm.  Does this make sense or would it not matter?

Comment: If you don't want to install an extra dependency, you should add bower_components folder to the paths. For example: *= require bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.   Let me know if this works

Comment: Or add the bower_components path like so in config/application.rb: config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "bower_components") and restart the server

Comment: I did put what you told me to do and I get basically a same error "couldn't find file 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap' with type 'text/css'". I'm supposed to put this in `application.css` right?

Comment: and no luck with `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "bower_components")`

Comment: What about using *= require bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap after you set the config.assets? Sorry about giving many wrong answers.  Not on my computer and can't test

Comment: It causes an error if I put that line in application.rb.

Comment: I meant putting the require line on the application.css (just remove bower_components from the path) once you had added the mentioned line in the application.rb file

Comment: Yeah, still no luck. I really don't understand what's causing an error.

Comment: In that case, I go back to my original suggestion (bower-rails).  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Use
    `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'components')` 
in the app.config.

Make sure the .bowerrc is set up as well with this

```
{
  "directory": "vendor/assets/components"
}
```

Ran into this issue as well.